# mysql_fetch not displaying

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
mysql_connect('localhost:3036', 'x', 'x');
mysql_select_db('extractor');
$baseSKUraw = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_category where tier_one='".$result1."' and tier_two ='".$result2."' ");
$baseSKU = mysql_fetch_array($baseSKUraw);
echo json_encode(array("error"=>0, "result1"=>$baseSKU['sku_base']));
```

The Json is returning `{"error":0,"result1":null}` but when I do a `"result1"=>"texthere"` it will return accordingly to my textbox.

- What went wrong here, I can't seem to display the `sku_base`?
- When should I use `mysql_fetch_array`? because I'm returning only 1
  result now?

---

var_dump(baseSKUraw);

```
resource(3) of type (mysql result)
{"error":0,"result1":null}
```

print_r($baseSKU);

```
resource(3) of type (mysql result)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => Tops
    [tier_one] => Tops
    [2] => Shortsleeve
    [tier_two] => Shortsleeve
    [3] => WTSS
    [sku_base] => WTSS
)
```

Comment: Should this be marked as `javascript` not `java`?

Comment: Did you try to do a var_dump($baseSKUraw), to see you get any results? Anyway try to use MYSQLi or PDO_MYSQL instead. all mysql_ functions are deprecated

Comment: add `echo mysql_error();` before your `json_encode` line, and then update the question with the output.

Comment: Check the result of `print_r($baseSKU); `

Comment: @Thanu ,Burhan Khalid , it's showing the following resource(3) of type (mysql result)
{"error":0,"result1":null}

Comment: @AmitGarg result updated in question. I'm trying to display the SKU_base by doing "result1"=>$baseSKU['sku_base']

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here,

```
$baseSKU = mysql_fetch_array($baseSKUraw);
echo json_encode(array("error"=>0, "result1"=>$baseSKU['sku_base']));
```

your using `mysql_fetch_array` and trying to use the results as if it was returned using `mysql_fetch_assoc`. When you use `mysql_fetch_array` you need to use the numerical index.

Comment: The default return mode of mysql_fetch_array() returns an array with both associative and numeric keys...

Comment: Hi @DevZer0 , Thank you. Can you explain the diff between array and assoc? Which is the correct one i should be using. how do you debug ajax? because print_r var_dump wont show unless i return json_encode. At the same time, i see people using print_r , var_dump , what should i use, both? btw i use firebug to check of json response, i think it's working good

Comment: just use the one that you feel gives you the best output, i personally use `print_r`

Comment: associative array is once you can access with a `key` index like $foo['hello'], $bar['world']. The other type is numeric and they have a 0 based numeric index.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).